# Special characters in drop-down list with Robot Framework (Selenium)

Tags: selenium, robotframework

just wondering if any of you know how to handle special characters with a website that contains a drop-down list. I scripted the following in Robot Framework (Selenium) to verify the contents of a drop-down list:

```
Verify all required fields and labels are present
    Verify a and lists of b for 'ööö'

Verify a and lists of b for '${xyz}'
    (...)
    Dropdown "{abc}" should contain options "${json_blabla["ABC"]["${xyz}"]}"
```

However, when trying to do that, I get the following error message when running the script:

```
Resolving variable '${json_blabla["ABC"]["ööö"]}' failed: KeyError: '\xc3\xb6\xc3\xb6\xc3\xb6'
```

Any idea how to get around this? I'm sure I saved everything in UTF-8 encoding, and I think the JSON file should be fine too, so I'm suspecting it's somewhere in the script I just showed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it:
It seems that it needs to be told explicitly that the string must be in Unicode, so one option to have it corrected is:

```
Dropdown "{abc}" should contain options "${json_blabla["ABC"][u"${xyz}"]}"
```

And voilà!

Thanks for voting & until next time!